# Kerio vpn client doesn't rebuild " /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc " after i deleted the file and reinstall kerio on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: installation, ubuntu-14.04, vpn

After some unsuccessful attempts to uninstall the kerio vpn client i deleted " /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc " and the " .deb " file i had downloaded(such a noob i am).Then i downloaded " kerio-control-vpnclient-9.0.0-442-linux-amd64.deb " and tried to install it by terminal.

```
     #cd Downloads   
     #sudo dpkg -i kerio-control-vpnclient-9.0.0-442-linux-amd64.deb
     #sudo dpkg-reconfigure kerio-control-vpnclient
```

reconfigured but didn't start."/etc/init.d/kerio-kvc" does not exist.No idea how to fix it.
Sorry for bad English.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must extract .deb file, copy and paste etc/init.d/kerio-kvc manually in /etc/init.d folder on your linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know need for somebody this answer still, but I've one:) (step by step)
Here intruction, how I installed kerio control vpn client (working only 8.1.1-1212-p3-linux) on linux machine 64bit (Ubuntu 18.04 & Mint 19), so:

1. sudo apt-get install debconf openssl
2. You need to download 8.1.1-1212-p3-linux.deb (32bit) for this link download.kerio.com/archive/download.php
3. cd Downloads
4. sudo dpkg -i kerio-control-vpnclient-8.1.1-1212-p3-linux.deb (will be error:)
5. sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture kerio-control-vpnclient-8.1.1-1212-p3-linux.deb:i386 (error again;)
6. sudo apt install -f (linux automatically downloads all necessary dependencies for 64 bit)
7. then we ask the server address - enter IP
8. then - say "Yes"
9. here we must to look on our certificate in Kerio admin panel on the server and enter it
10. and then enter your login&password for connect to the server
11. sudo /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc start

Kerio starting and we can connect to the server, if you already have a customized RDP client or some other protocol.
Good luck:)